# How can I access a webDAV folder as a UNC share?

Tags: webdav

First of all I'm just getting to know about webDAV and appreciate your
patience.
I have a virtual directory on IIS 6 (windows 2003) which is based on a network
share on a file server, different from web server. Something like
`www.mysite.com/myreports` where myreport is based on `\\myfileserver\reports`.
I have been asked by network folks to not use the UNC path like that for
security reason and try to explore using webDAV. What I have been told is
webDAV can give me a UNC path without requiring to open the ports required
for a file server UNC path. Then I can use the new UNC path to map my virtual
directory and my asp.net code will not require any change.

Help: Being new to webDAV, I did some research over the web. I now can create
a web folder in fileserver. I put IIS on file server as well. I can browse
the content as http:://fileserver/mywebDAVreports which is based on reports
folder.

But I don't know how to get a UNC for this web folder to be able to map my
virtual directory on web server.
I appreciate any help on this.
Regards,
Amar

Answer (score 3):

I got it working. I did 3 things to get there.

1- I uninstalled Frontpage extension 2000 from the file server.

2- I removed all custom headers from the file server's IIS

3-I had anonymous access on website roor but not on the virtual directory of web folder. I made change to get consistency. I disabled anonymous access and enabled Integrated authentication on the website as well as on the virtual directory.

This allowed me to access the web folder using UNC path. I can now use this UNC path as physical path to a virtual directory on my web server ( different from file server). Yes I could map the virtual directory not to the root of the webDAV share but to one of its subfolders. So http:/mywebserver/Reports virtual directory is mapped to \fileserver\mywebDavShare\MyReports. I can now see teh files and folders under MyReports in IIS Manager.
Thanks,
AR

Comment: Thanks for providing your solution!  Go ahead and mark your question as "answered" by clicking the box.