# Accessing public server using UNC path

Tags: webdav, unc

My goal is to access public server using UNC path `\\server_ip\folder` syntax. My ISP is blocking port 445, so i cannot access server using `SMB` protocol. The questions are:

1. There are still no easy method to force windows use `SMB` protocol via other port than 445 (for example 80)?
2. That leaves me `WebDAV` protocol. How to force windows explorer to use this protocol? I setup `WebDAV` server. I can access files via browser, but not with UNC path in windows explorer. I cannot access `WebDAV` server from local machine and from remote machine using explorer. I tried `\\ip:80\folder` and `\\ip@80\folder` - they refused to connect. I also edited `Network Connections - Advanced Settings - Provider Order` and made `Web Client Network` first and tried to access using simple form `\\ip\folder`, but wireshark showed that it was accessed using port 445. So still not `WebDAV`.

EDIT:

Of cource I can use UNC, there is no doubt. For example, see:
[How can I access a webDAV folder as a UNC share?](https://serverfault.com/questions/163559/how-can-i-access-a-webdav-folder-as-a-unc-share)

Ok if you don't like I'm doing over public, then how can I access it in my LAB. WebDAV folder is on my local PC and I'm accessing it via UNC on my local PC. I see windows cannot access. HTTP/1.1 405 Method not alowed.

IIS is version 10.0.17134.1

EDIT: so nobody who managed to do it would tell?

Comment: Please don't. This is a bad idea. Use a VPN solution (OpenVPN, Microsoft DirectAccess, IPSec, whatever), use Sharepoint, use anything but don't expose Windows ports to the public.

Comment: Other solutions are ok, but this is for some testing, not for real sharing

Comment: You do testing in a lab. Not on a real life production network over the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have configure a webdav server windows should connect to it, but you cannot use UNC path, you have to use the URL of your webdav, follow this guide: [Reference](https://uvacollab.screenstepslive.com/s/help/m/sitetools/l/611578-how-do-i-set-up-webdav-for-windows-10-or-8)

1. right click on Computer
2. Add network location -> Next
3. select "Choose a custom netwrok location"
4. insert the webdav link -> Next
5. Insert credential

**NOTE:** by default the windows client will refuse to connect to a plain webdav server, use authentication and TLS for your connection.

as per @Lenniey says, do not expose standard windows port (especially SMB protocol which is not pretty secure) some ransomware were use SMB vulnerability (should fixed now) to propagate them self over the network. To access the server with UNC path use a VPN like @Lenniey says.

Or think about to use different protocol like ssh.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider, I'll improve the answer as per you suggestion